# How to I create a ticking time series with Reactive Extensions for Python (RxPY)?

Tags: python, reactive-programming, rx-py

### My Setup:

I have a list of stock price data in (time, price) tuples:

```
from datetime import datetime
prices = [(datetime(2015, 1, 9), 101.9), (datetime(2015, 1, 12), 101.5), (datetime(2015, 1, 13), 101.7)]
```

which I want to make into an [RxPY](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY) `Observable` so that I may backtest a trading strategy tick-by-tick:

```
def myStrategy(date, price):   # SELL if date is a Monday and price is above 101.6
    strategy = 'SELL' if date.weekday() and price > 101.6 else 'BUY'
    print 'date=%s price=%s strategy=%s' % (date, price, strategy)
```

I wish to start backtesting from 12 Jan 2015 so I assume I must use the following scheduler:

```
from rx.concurrency import HistoricalScheduler
scheduler = HistoricalScheduler(datetime(2015, 1, 12))
```

To run my backtest I do:

```
from rx import Observable
observable = Observable.from_iterable(prices, scheduler=scheduler).timestamp()
observable.subscribe(lambda price: myStrategy(price.timestamp, price.value))
scheduler.start()
```

### Problem:

I expected to see:

```
date=2015-01-12 00:00:00 price=101.5 strategy=BUY
date=2015-01-13 00:00:00 price=101.7 strategy=SELL
```

but I got

```
date=2015-12-20 08:43:45.882000 price=(datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 9, 0, 0), 101.9) strategy=SELL
date=2015-12-20 08:43:45.882000 price=(datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 12, 0, 0), 101.5) strategy=SELL
date=2015-12-20 08:43:45.882000 price=(datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 13, 0, 0), 101.7) strategy=SELL
```

The problems are that:

- The timestamps are wrong: I get today's date of `2015-12-20 08:43:45.882000` instead of the historic dates (e.g. `datetime(2015, 1, 12)`)
- The price still contains the time component
- The scheduler did not start on 12 Jan 2015 as I requested, since I see that the data point from 9 Jan 2015 was still used.

I also tried using `scheduler.now()`:

```
observable.subscribe(lambda price: myStrategy(scheduler.now(), price.value))
```

but then the date was stuck on `date=2015-01-12 00:00:00` for some reason:

```
date=2015-01-12 00:00:00 price=(datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 9, 0, 0), 101.9) strategy=BUY
date=2015-01-12 00:00:00 price=(datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 12, 0, 0), 101.5) strategy=BUY
date=2015-01-12 00:00:00 price=(datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 13, 0, 0), 101.7) strategy=BUY
```

How do I fix the above and obtain the result I originally expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also very new to rx,

- I think the timestamp() needs the scheduler parameter. Otherwise it
  works on some default scheduler as per rx docs.
- You are passing the entire tuple (date,price) as price to
  myStrategy() thats why it is printing the date.

"timestamp by default operates on the timeout Scheduler, but also has a variant that allows you to specify the Scheduler by passing it in as a parameter."
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timestamp.html

There is documentation only for rxjs , but the beauty of rx is that everything follows.

Please see if this can work for you.

```
    observable = Observable.from_iterable(prices,scheduler=scheduler).timestamp(scheduler=scheduler)
    observable.subscribe(lambda price: myStrategy(price.timestamp, price.value[1]))
    scheduler.start()
```